# Using DiskVolumeInfo (Cluster Failover API)

Tags: winapi, windows-server-2008, failovercluster

I found the `DiskVolumeInfo` property -- I'd like to use it to get some disk information in a clustered setup.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309235(v=vs.85).aspx

The problem is I have no idea what technology is required to get this data.  This doesn't resemble the standard C/C++/C#/VB format of function/method reference.

**Question: How do I get the DiskVolumeInfo data?**

Ideally I could write the binary output directly to a file, say data.bin.

Any ideas would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process for getting object properties is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Looks like you need to call the [`ClusterResourceControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with a handle to the physical disk resource and the [`CLUSCTL_RESOURCE_GET_PRIVATE_PROPERTIES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control code.  You can then use [`ResUtilFindBinaryProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to extract the DiskVolumeInfo property from the property list returned.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested:

As given [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ab830d46-096d-4553-abda-2a8ffcdef9ce/how-to-get-the-volume-guid-for-the-cluster-volume?forum=winserverClustering) CLUSCTL_RESOURCE_STORAGE_GET_DISK_INFO_EX is a better way to do this.